# git merge default options

Tags: windows, git

When I `git merge` a branch in another one, I like to pass the `--edit --log` options. I would like to make it automatic, but cannot get how.

What I tried:

#### Set the `[merge]` part of my global `.gitconfig`

```
[merge]
    edit = true
    log = 20
```

Git merge does not change its default behavior.

*Note: I believe those options are not available for configuration file as I cannot see them in the output of* `git help -c | grep merge`

#### Create an alias of `merge`

If I define my alias that first way:

```
[alias]
    merge = merge --edit --log
```

or that second one:

```
[alias]
    merge = "! git merge $* --edit --log #"
```

Then I cannot see any change in git's behavior.

If I call my alias anything else that `merge`, then it works as expected (adding edit and log options).

---

So, is there any solution to make `git merge` use `--edit --log` by default?

Comment: Short answer : name it differently. Treat commands as reserved keywords.

Comment: (to emphasize one point on RomainValeri's comment) : treat *built-in* commands (`merge`, `add`, `checkout` ...) as reserveed keywords

Comment: The alias solution was only a workaround: I would have liked to enforce the `edit=true ; log = 20` options of the `[merge]` section, so that it is the default behavior for all the software that send git merge commands

Comment: That's tricky because it wouldn't be just git that would need to support that. Probably libgit2 would also need to support it because that's what is normally implemented in other pieces of software that support git (like IDEs).

Comment: @eftshift0: should I conclude that what I want to do is simply not supported? I thought I was missing sth, but if is just not possible, I accept working with an alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others mentioned in comments, if you name an alias `merge`, Git completely ignores it.  That is, given:

```
[alias]
    merge = foo
    marge = foo
```

running `git merge` runs the standard `git merge`, but running `git marge` gets you an error about `git foo` not being a Git command (assuming you have not made yourself a `git-foo` command, of course).

This is true for all standard Git commands.

---

There is no `merge.edit` setting.  Or—equivalently—you can set `merge.edit` to anything you like,<sup>1</sup> but `git merge` never inspects the setting so it makes no difference.

There *is* a `merge.log` setting.  This defaults to `false`, i.e., if you have not set it, or if you set it to `false`, `git merge` behaves the way it does by default.  Setting it to `true` has the same effect as setting it to the number 20.

The default for `git merge` is `--edit` unless a merge message is specified with `-m` or `-F`.  If you use the merge run by `git pull`, the `--edit` action is also the default.

The one special case where `merge.log` has no effect is a *fast-forward*, which is not a merge at all.<sup>2</sup>  Since no new commit is being created by the fast-forward action, there is no place to put any messages, so `merge.log` is ignored as well.

All of this is specific to the command line as implemented by Git itself.  If you're using other software (e.g., Eclipse), that other software probably has its own implementation and may completely ignore the way *Git* does things.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git's settings framework is very general, so it allows you to set all kinds of things that Git never checks.  This has a nice side effect: it means you can write your own commands that use these settings.  It has a bad side effect too: if you misspell a setting name, for instance, you never get any warning about this.

[The `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) is supposed to have a master list of all settings that are meaningful to all of Git's commands.  Note that sometimes things slip: e.g., `log.decorate` can be set to `auto`, and this was true for a long time but not *documented* until Git 2.9.0.

<sup>2</sup>I think it's a bit unfortunate that Git calls this a *fast-forward merge* in places.